# Magnetic field very far from long solenoid

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

Hi I have a short question. Given a very long solenoid consisting of $n$ closely wound turns per unit length (hence we can take the turns as circular) on a cylinder of radius $R$ and carrying a steady current $I$. How do we know that the magnetic field approaches zero as you go very far away from the solenoid?

Thanks.

Comment: This paper might interest you http://scitation.aip.org/content/aapt/journal/ajp/69/7/10.1119/1.1362694

Comment: https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0143-0807/38/1/015201/meta

Answer (score 1):

The field decays with distance, the Biot-Savart law tells us this.